# How to give a user permission to everything except env files?

Tags: permissions, sudo

So I need to create a ssh login for a colleague of mine that will allow him to install new things (most notably python packages) and restart services. I would be happy to give him full permissions to everything except a) few env files that have my access keys and passwords and b) elevating his permissions even more.

What would be a good way to go about doing this?

I'm running Ubuntu 14

Comment: How is they going to install python packages ? Through a package manager? If Yes, then just give them sudo access only to the package manager

Comment: @ebal If you give me `sudo dpkg` or `sudo apt` or similar then I have full root access to your machine; just need to create a post-install script that does anything I want :-)

Comment: That is way my dear friend, I will never give you sudo access :P

Comment: Can the python packages be installed in his home directory (which doesn't require any special permissions)?

Comment: Yes they're installing through pip. And I would prefer the packages to be installed in the default folder.

Comment: The problem is that every now and then they'll probably need to fix some random issues. Like today while I was at work they managed to screw up MySQL and so all my sites stopped working for the day (not a problem at all). And I have complete trust in them that if they manged to screw it up, they'll get it back up too, except they need privileges to run those commands.

Comment: If someone needs administrative access to perform unknown tasks there isn't a good way to prevent them from running any command. `/etc/sudoers` can blacklist commands (using `!command`) but there are many easy ways to circumvent it, and is mostly meant to remind someone not to do something rather than truly stop them.

Comment: Alternatively you can host the files you don't want changed on another machine, export them over NFS read only, and mount them on the target machine. You can create symlinks as needed to point to the nfs mount. This is a bit messy, but is really the only way I could think of to stop root from editing a file: for it not to be on that machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't give a user access to “everything except for a few files”. If they can modify the system configuration then they can change those settings and give themselves full access. If they can install services that run as root then they can install a program that will give them full access. If they can install programs that you run then they can install a program that will give out your secrets the first time you run it.

If you don't trust your fellow administrators, don't store any secrets on the machine.

Put your confidential files and the services that need to be co-administered on separate machines. You can of course use virtual machines or containers, they don't have to be separate physical machines. Run the co-administered services in a VM/container and give your colleague administrator access only in the VM/container.